# Unit testing a metodo de instancia vue

Tags: vue.js

estoy aprendiendo a hacer unit testing en vue. Quisiera saber como hacer un test a un metodo. Estoy usando jest y vue test utils. En la documentacion de vue no encuentro nada parecido para hacer test a un metodo.

hasta ahora, lo que tengo es lo siguiente

```
introducir el código aquíimport { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Usuario from '@/components/Usuario.vue'

describe('componente Usuario.vue', () => {
it('calls testMethod on mount', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Usuario, {
        methods: {
            activarUsuario
        }
    })
    wrapper.vm.activarUsuario = jest.fn()

    expect(activarUsuario).toBeCalled()
});
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas testear que el boton ha sido llamado y mockear la funcion puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Usuario from '@/components/Usuario.vue'

describe('componente Usuario.vue', () => {
it('calls testMethod on mount', () => {
    const activarUsuario = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Usuario, {
        methods: {
            activarUsuario
        }
    })
    expect(activarUsuario).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    const button = wrapper.find('button'); // aqui buscarias el elemento que ejecuta el metodo
    button.trigger('click'); //simulamos el evento click
    expect(activarUsuario).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // validamos el click
});
```

También puedes testear el metodo directamente de esta manera

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Usuario from '@/components/Usuario.vue'

describe('componente Usuario.vue', () => {
it('calls testMethod on mount', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Usuario);
    wrapper.vm.activarUsuario();
    expect(wrapper.vm.usuarioActivado).toBe(true); // aqui validarias lo que esperas que haya hecho tu metodo
});
```